# meaning of CRASH REPORT

Tags: erlang

i am writing a proxy where i create one gen_server for one socket and i also try to implement the Proxy-Connection = Keep-Alive mechanism.

When i test my software, some request works fine, but sometimes i get the following crash report :

```
05:39:33.481 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.110.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: {timeout_value,[{gen_server,loop,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
05:39:33.483 [error] Supervisor lh_server_sup had child lh_server started with lh_server:start_link(#Port<0.6247>) at <0.110.0> exit with reason timeout_value in context child_terminated
```

I don't know how to interpret this error and where to search. Can somebody help me to find the bug?

Thanks,
Ulf

Answer (score 2):

timeout_value usually happens when you use construction

```
receive
... 
after something -> ..
end
```

when something is not integer and not the atom 'hibernate'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i found the problem in my code. :-) The problem was, that i returned something like {noreply, normal, State} which is interpreted by the gen_server loop/6 as a time_out value. After changing it to {noreply, State} everything works fine.